# Why would my CPU suddenly get much hotter than it used to?

Tags: cpu, temperature, intel-core-i7

I run an [i7-2700K](http://ark.intel.com/products/61275/Intel-Core-i7-2700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) on a [DZ68BC](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dz68bc.html), which I've assembled about a year ago. I've used the stock Intel fan without additional thermal compound and it worked flawlessly ever since.

I've had the Intel Desktop Utilities installed ever since I set up the machine. Lately, I've been seeing a lot of these:
[image]

I grabbed a can of pressurized air and cleaned out the inside of the case. Didn't do anything in regards to temperature.
So I figured it couldn't hurt to replace the thermal compound between the heat sink and the CPU, so that's what I did. And here's how it looked:

[image]
[image]

So, I cleaned it all up with alcohol and applied new thermal paste:

[image]
[image]

So, after this whole ordeal, pretty much nothing has changed:

[image]

Before I replaced the thermal compound, I would get temperature reading of >90°C in the BIOS, after replacing it, I got a reading of 78°C.

In the OS, the temperatures are much lower, yet, still concerning. Under moderate load it will jump to the 85-90°C area rather quickly.

Why is the CPU suddenly getting this hot and how should I remedy this situation?

Comment: Can you try a different CPU cooler, either from Intel or other vendors, and check the temps?

Comment: @sabrefresco: I don't have any replacement parts I could try at the moment. But I'll look into it

Comment: Can you check your fan speed, using Speedfan or any other program or even from the BIOS? At temps close to the T-case, you should have around 2500-3000rpm. With you current temp (78C), I would expect it to run at more 2100rpm.

Comment: @sabrefresco: When running Prime95, I get these readings from Desktop Utilities: http://i.imgur.com/VhMqjol.png I've never seen it go beyond 2400rpm. Maybe the stock fan can't even go any higher. I also ordered an [EKL Alpenföhn Himalaya](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Alpenf%C3%B6hn-Himalaya-Socket-1156-1155/dp/B005FYEH9Q) which should be delivered in the morning. I'll report back :)

Comment: I wonder if your fan is running at the correct speed while under a 50% load. Of course going from a value higher then 90°C to 78°C is a enough of difference to make what you did worth awhile. Do you notice any noise with the stock fan that sounds different? The temperatures you are getting at 30-60% load should really concern you. Those temperatures at 100% load could in theory be accepted depending on the length of time you were under that load of course. As for the RPM of a INTEL stock fan it can go up over 4000 RPM http://communities.intel.com/thread/32111

Comment: @Ramhound: It's hard for me to judge what's "normal" at this point as I haven't been properly monitoring the system prior to noticing these issues. There is hardly any noise coming from the computer, so there's also no unusual noise from the fan.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - Abnormal noise would be the fan basically not rotating because the ball joint was broken ( happen to me before ) max RPM was a couple hundred RPM in my case.  Of course you could hear it basically "limping" along in my case.  It really does sound like the fan might be on its last leg, which is the reason its not going beyond 2500 RPM, and thus temperatures are starting to rise.

Comment: excuse me for reviving this 3 years old topic, but I want to ask for clarification on one point. When you said "I've used the stock Intel fan without additional thermal compound and it worked flawlessly ever since." does this mean that you were using the pre-applied grease that came "printed" on the stock cooler? or did you mean that you used the same third party grease since you first assembled your PC?

Comment: @Nisse The former. I used what was pre-applied on the cooler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, today I've replaced the stock Intel heat sink/fan with an [EKL Alpenföhn Himalaya](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Alpenf%C3%B6hn-Himalaya-Socket-1156-1155/dp/B005FYEH9Q).

[image]

Now, *shockingly*, the temperatures are much lower:
[image]

Still a little high though. I no longer get any annoying temperature warnings, so I'm happy for now. After replacing the thermal compound as well as the heat sink and fan, I really don't see what's left to do. Especially given that I didn't see any cause for the sudden increase in heat.